# Laravel / Quarx login authentication route incorrect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've installed Laravel 5.4 and Quarx v2.3 out of the box and the site is up and running, all routes working properly for the default template pages. Site is installed on domain.com/subdir/

Page routes are all working correctly:
domain.com/subdir/
domain.com/subdir/blog/
domain.com/subdir/events/
domain.com/subdir/faqs/
domain.com/subdir/gallery/
domain.com/subdir/login/

However, something is wrong with the login authentication routes. Login form submission redirects to domain.com/login, causing a 404.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thx!

Comment: It would help if we could see the code.

Comment: which code would you like to see? everything is literally out of the box laravel/quarx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There is a bug in the quarx auth page generation. Can be fixed by rebuilding/overwriting the quarx auth pages with the stock laravel auth pages by running:

```
php artisan make:auth
```